# dart: check list data from between two dates

Tags: flutter, dart

### I have two financial date like 2023-04-01 and 2025-03-31, so here I want to check my which data are between that dates.

So I want a algorithm for it,I can't make it.
Please help me. Thank you!

This is my data list.

```
[
  {
    interest_date: 2028-08-16,
    total_return: 20,
    640.00,
    interest_frequency: 20,
    640.00,
    bond_name: 10.32%APCRDABONDS(STRPPE)16/08/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2028-05-16,
    total_return: 20,
    640.00,
    interest_frequency: 20,
    640.00,
    bond_name: 10.32%APCRDABONDS(STRPPE)16/08/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2028-02-16,
    total_return: 20,
    640.00,
    interest_frequency: 20,
    640.00,
    bond_name: 10.32%APCRDABONDS(STRPPE)16/08/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2027-11-16,
    total_return: 20,
    640.00,
    interest_frequency: 20,
    640.00,
    bond_name: 10.32%APCRDABONDS(STRPPE)16/08/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2027-08-16,
    total_return: 20,
    640.00,
    interest_frequency: 20,
    640.00,
    bond_name: 10.32%APCRDABONDS(STRPPE)16/08/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2027-05-16,
    total_return: 20,
    640.00,
    interest_frequency: 20,
    640.00,
    bond_name: 10.32%APCRDABONDS(STRPPE)16/08/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2027-02-16,
    total_return: 20,
    640.00,
    interest_frequency: 20,
    640.00,
    bond_name: 10.32%APCRDABONDS(STRPPE)16/08/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2026-11-16,
    total_return: 20,
    640.00,
    interest_frequency: 20,
    640.00,
    bond_name: 10.32%APCRDABONDS(STRPPE)16/08/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2026-08-16,
    total_return: 20,
    640.00,
    interest_frequency: 20,
    640.00,
    bond_name: 10.32%APCRDABONDS(STRPPE)16/08/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2026-05-16,
    total_return: 20,
    640.00,
    interest_frequency: 20,
    640.00,
    bond_name: 10.32%APCRDABONDS(STRPPE)16/08/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2026-02-16,
    total_return: 20,
    640.00,
    interest_frequency: 20,
    640.00,
    bond_name: 10.32%APCRDABONDS(STRPPE)16/08/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2025-11-16,
    total_return: 20,
    640.00,
    interest_frequency: 20,
    640.00,
    bond_name: 10.32%APCRDABONDS(STRPPE)16/08/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2025-08-16,
    total_return: 20,
    640.00,
    interest_frequency: 20,
    640.00,
    bond_name: 10.32%APCRDABONDS(STRPPE)16/08/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2025-05-16,
    total_return: 20,
    640.00,
    interest_frequency: 20,
    640.00,
    bond_name: 10.32%APCRDABONDS(STRPPE)16/08/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2025-02-16,
    total_return: 20,
    640.00,
    interest_frequency: 20,
    640.00,
    bond_name: 10.32%APCRDABONDS(STRPPE)16/08/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2024-11-16,
    total_return: 20,
    640.00,
    interest_frequency: 20,
    640.00,
    bond_name: 10.32%APCRDABONDS(STRPPE)16/08/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2024-08-16,
    total_return: 20,
    640.00,
    interest_frequency: 20,
    640.00,
    bond_name: 10.32%APCRDABONDS(STRPPE)16/08/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2024-05-16,
    total_return: 20,
    640.00,
    interest_frequency: 20,
    640.00,
    bond_name: 10.32%APCRDABONDS(STRPPE)16/08/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2024-02-16,
    total_return: 20,
    640.00,
    interest_frequency: 20,
    640.00,
    bond_name: 10.32%APCRDABONDS(STRPPE)16/08/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2023-11-16,
    total_return: 20,
    640.00,
    interest_frequency: 20,
    640.00,
    bond_name: 10.32%APCRDABONDS(STRPPE)16/08/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2023-08-16,
    total_return: 20,
    640.00,
    interest_frequency: 20,
    640.00,
    bond_name: 10.32%APCRDABONDS(STRPPE)16/08/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2027-12-27,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UPPCLBONDS(SERIESII-SUBSERIESI)20/01/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2027-09-27,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UPPCLBONDS(SERIESII-SUBSERIESI)20/01/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2027-06-27,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UPPCLBONDS(SERIESII-SUBSERIESI)20/01/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2027-03-27,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UPPCLBONDS(SERIESII-SUBSERIESI)20/01/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2026-12-27,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UPPCLBONDS(SERIESII-SUBSERIESI)20/01/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2026-09-27,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UPPCLBONDS(SERIESII-SUBSERIESI)20/01/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2026-06-27,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UPPCLBONDS(SERIESII-SUBSERIESI)20/01/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2026-03-27,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UPPCLBONDS(SERIESII-SUBSERIESI)20/01/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2025-12-27,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UPPCLBONDS(SERIESII-SUBSERIESI)20/01/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2025-09-27,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UPPCLBONDS(SERIESII-SUBSERIESI)20/01/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2025-06-27,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UPPCLBONDS(SERIESII-SUBSERIESI)20/01/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2025-03-27,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UPPCLBONDS(SERIESII-SUBSERIESI)20/01/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2024-12-27,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UPPCLBONDS(SERIESII-SUBSERIESI)20/01/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2024-09-27,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UPPCLBONDS(SERIESII-SUBSERIESI)20/01/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2024-06-27,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UPPCLBONDS(SERIESII-SUBSERIESI)20/01/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2024-03-27,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UPPCLBONDS(SERIESII-SUBSERIESI)20/01/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2023-12-27,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UPPCLBONDS(SERIESII-SUBSERIESI)20/01/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2023-09-27,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UPPCLBONDS(SERIESII-SUBSERIESI)20/01/2028
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2026-03-18,
    total_return: 97,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 97,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 9.75%HINDUJALEYLANDFINANCELIMITED18/09/2026
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2025-03-18,
    total_return: 97,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 97,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 9.75%HINDUJALEYLANDFINANCELIMITED18/09/2026
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2024-03-18,
    total_return: 97,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 97,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 9.75%HINDUJALEYLANDFINANCELIMITED18/09/2026
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2025-01-23,
    total_return: 68,
    750.00,
    interest_frequency: 68,
    750.00,
    bond_name: 13.75%THESOUTHINDIANBANKLTD.PERP.2025
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2024-01-23,
    total_return: 68,
    750.00,
    interest_frequency: 68,
    750.00,
    bond_name: 13.75%THESOUTHINDIANBANKLTD.PERP.2025
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2024-08-05,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UGROCAPITALLIMITED05/08/2024
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2024-07-05,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UGROCAPITALLIMITED05/08/2024
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2024-06-05,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UGROCAPITALLIMITED05/08/2024
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2024-05-05,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UGROCAPITALLIMITED05/08/2024
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2024-04-05,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UGROCAPITALLIMITED05/08/2024
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2024-03-05,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UGROCAPITALLIMITED05/08/2024
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2024-02-05,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UGROCAPITALLIMITED05/08/2024
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2024-01-05,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UGROCAPITALLIMITED05/08/2024
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2023-12-05,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UGROCAPITALLIMITED05/08/2024
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2023-11-05,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UGROCAPITALLIMITED05/08/2024
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2023-10-05,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UGROCAPITALLIMITED05/08/2024
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2023-09-05,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UGROCAPITALLIMITED05/08/2024
  },
  {
    interest_date: 2023-08-05,
    total_return: 101,
    500.00,
    interest_frequency: 101,
    500.00,
    bond_name: 10.15%UGROCAPITALLIMITED05/08/2024
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the list with [`where()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/where.html) and parse the date to a `DateTime` object using `DateTime.tryParse()`, then use `DateTime.isBefore()` and `DateTime.isAfter()` to perform the filtering.

```dart
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = ...;
    final DateTime startDate = DateTime(2023, 4, 1);
    final DateTime endDate = DateTime(2025, 3, 31);

    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> filtered = data.where((element) {
      final interestDate = DateTime.tryParse(element['interest_date'] as String);
      if (interestDate == null) return false;
      return interestDate.isAfter(startDate) && interestDate.isBefore(endDate);
    }).toList();
```

You may want to check out [filtering on iterables](https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables#filtering).